# How to escape single-quote (apostrophe) in string using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a SQL query like this:-

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
   "SELECT * FROM `products_keywords` WHERE `product_type` = '" . $product_type . "' ");
```

I don't know what will be the value in the **$product_type** variable. But Now, I am getting **Men's Shirt** in **$product_type** variable which is causing the syntax error in my SQL query. I am sure this error is due to the single quote in **Men's Shirt** value. How I escape this value according to my query? And how to check if there is **single quote** in my **$product_type** variable and then escape it according to my query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assign **Men's Shirt** to a  PHP `Variable` and use it. Like `$prod = "Men's Shirt";`

Comment: Use parameter binding and you wont have this problem :)

Comment: It seems you missed the whole point of [prepared SQL statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). One of its purposes is to avoid generating SQL queries by string concatenation.

Comment: @RakeshSojitra thanks for reply. can you please more elaborate? and edit my query according to question. Thanks.

Comment: $query = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM `products_keywords` WHERE `product_type` = :product_type');
$query->execute([':product_type' => $product_type]); # No need to escape it!

Comment: I voted to reopen this question, after it was closed as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/. The questions are clearly not the same, even if the answers are similar.

Comment: @junaidafzal, please remember to upvote answers that were helpful to you, and mark the accepted checkmark on the answer that helped you the best.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is that you don't need to. The proper way to use PDO's prepare is like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
   "SELECT * FROM `products_keywords` WHERE `product_type` = ?");
```

This is the whole point of using a prepared statement. Then you [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) the parameter as follows:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $product_type)
```

Proof,

Schema:

```
create table `products_keywords`
(   `id` int not null,
    `products_keywords` varchar(1000) not null,
    `product_type` varchar(100) not null
);
insert `products_keywords` (`id`,`products_keywords`,`product_type`) values  
(1,'zoom lawn cut mower',"Lawn Mower"),
(2,'stylish torso Polo','Men\'s Shirt');
```

View data:

```
select * from `products_keywords`;
+----+---------------------+--------------+
| id | products_keywords   | product_type |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | zoom lawn cut mower | Lawn Mower   |
|  2 | stylish torso Polo  | Men's Shirt  |
+----+---------------------+--------------+
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    // turn on error reporting, or wonder why nothing is happening at times
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);    

    $servername="localhost";
    $dbname="so_gibberish";
    $username="nate123";
    $password="openSesame1";

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        $product_type="Men's Shirt";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products_keywords` WHERE `product_type` = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $product_type);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            echo $row['id'].", ".$row['products_keywords'].", ".$row['product_type']."<br/>";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'pdo problemo: ' . $e->getMessage();   // dev not production code
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Browser:

[image]

Comment: How use this in like clause with wildcard?

Comment: just use `where product_type like ?`

Comment: why don't you just try??

Comment: can you please give me escape character solution please?

Comment: No I will not because that's not the right way to use PDO. Then you might has well start using mysql_* functions

Comment: @junaidafzal Just use `LIKE` as normal in your SQL query as suggested by e4c5 and add the wildcard(s) to your parameter string; e.g:  `$stmt->bindParameter(1, '%' . $product_type . '%');`

Comment: +1 But you don't even need to use bindParam(). You can just pass an array to execute(). I don't understand why so many PHP developers think bindParam() is necessary.

Comment: Or `$stmt->execute(['%' . $product_type . '%']);` as @BillKarwin quite rightly points out ;)

Comment: Or even `$stmt->execute(["%$product_type%"]);` I don't know why people use the ugly string-concat syntax when you can just put a variable into a double-quoted string.

Comment: @drew I think you have the golden vote that can close without waiting for the others! Interesting thing about dupes coming up ini the chat, I didn't know about it. Guess i should drop in there sometimes. Thanks for this and all the other great things you have done

Answer (score 2):

I would actually suggest doing it the following way:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
   'SELECT * FROM `products_keywords` WHERE `product_type` = :product_type');
$res = $stmt->execute(array(':product_type' => $product_type));
```

This way you don't need to escape anything and your query is safe.

Comment: How use this in like clause with wildcard?

Comment: $res = $stmt->execute(array(':product_type' => $product_type.'%'));

and in the query string replace "equals character" with a "LIKE"

Comment: can you please give me escape character solution please?

Answer (score 2):

In order to insert a quote in a PDO statement, just use the `addslashes` function. For example:

```
function insert($tagName)
{
    $tagName = addslashes($tagName);
    $rs = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO tags (tagName) VALUES ('$tagName')");
    $rs->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep asking for a solution to escape the apostrophe. I agree with the other comments and answers that you should get used to using query parameters. It's cleaner and easier.

But PDO does actually have a function for escaping. It's called [PDO::quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php):

```
$product_type_quoted = $pdo->quote($product_type);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
   "SELECT * FROM `products_keywords` 
    WHERE `product_type` = $product_type_quoted");
```

Notice that quote() escapes the string as needed, and also adds single-quotes around it, so you don't need to do that when you use that variable in your SQL string.

Read the documentation for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php In fact, you could have answered this question yourself by spending a few minutes reading the PDO documentation.