# how to query this statement ( where name like '%job's you%') in mysql

Tags: mysql, search

I am try select from mysql database with this

> select * from mytable where where name like '%job's you%');

It's give me error message. How to fix it? thank for you help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape apostrophe (') in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single-quote (apostrophe) in string using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634968/how-to-escape-single-quote-apostrophe-in-string-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

The ' in *job's* is escaping your query and the ) shouldn't be there. Try:

```
select * from mytable where where name like '%job\'s you%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two time where  , an improper )  and you have a single quote inside so you should wrap with double quotes

```
select * from mytable where name like "%job's you%";
```

Answer (score 0):

The ' in "job's" is escaping your query, you can try:

`select * from mytable where where name like "%job's you%"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `real_escape_string`.

```
$variable = $mysqli->real_escape_string("job's you");
$query = $mysqli->query("select * from mytable where where name like '%".$variable."%')");
```

Please follow the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for more details.